# Overloading assignment operator in CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, cuda

To fully utilize a CUDA capable GPU which uses the sm_21 architecture it is required to write your kernel with vector datatypes, like uint2.

Imagine a line in a kernel that looks like this:

```
uint2 a = make_uint2 (123);
```

This works fine. The value 123 is stored to both, a.x and a.y. But it is annoying to read an write, especially when you have to write large code blocks and initialize lots of variables.

I am used to writing plain C code, so I am not a C++ geek. Maybe what I am searching for is pretty simple.

I know it is possible to "overload" an operator. My question is: Is it possible to overload the assignment operator, too?

I tried this:

```
inline __device__ uint2 operator = (int a)
{
  return make_uint2 (a, a);
}
```

But it fails with the error message:

> error: "operator=" must be a member function

Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* possible to overload the assignment operator, but (as the error message is telling you) it must be a member function. That means to use it you must create a class to act as a "wrapper" for the `uint2`. When you do that, however, chances are pretty good that you won't actually need/want to overload `operator=` -- rather, you'll just create a ctor that creates an instance of your wrapper from a `uint2` and another that makes one from an `int`. Those will be used to create an instance of the wrapper from the value you provide, and that temporary instance will be assigned to the target. Code would look something like this:

```
class uint_2 {
    uint2 value;
public:
    uint_2(uint2 init) : value(init) {}
    uint_2(int init) : value(make_uint2(init)) {}

    operator uint2() { return value; }
};
```

Especially given that you're using CUDA, questions about efficiency are likely to arise, so I'll address them up-front: under normal circumstances, this would probably impose no overhead. I'm a bit less certain, however, about the situation with CUDA, and whether you'd be able (for example) to use `__device__` in the code above. My immediate guess is probably not, but to be honest I really just don't know -- I wrote a *little* CUDA code years ago when it was new, but I'm pretty sure I never tried this. I doubt I ever new the rules for sure, but if I did, I don't remember them any more.

Comment: I'll meassure if it creates any overhead in terms of efficiency and post the results here. Thanks for help.

Comment: OK, I got it working! About your efficiency doubts: The ptx code looks no different to the scalar version (except the additional code that it has to produce). If there is any overhead due to the class, llvm's optimizer completly optimizes it away.